# Is there an online tool to change a color gradient?

Tags: software-recommendation, gradient, color-conversion

I want to change the color gradient in this image from yellow to white or transparent. Is there an online tool that can achieve this in an easy fashion?

[image]
Which online tool can I just that can achieve this in the easiest way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: software/site recommendation

Answer (score -2):

Overlooked an option on Lunapic. This worked for me:
https://www194.lunapic.com/editor/?action=transparent